# Angular2 boostrap not bootstrapping?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am new to Angular2 coming from a Python background, and I admittedly am completely lost at this point in the Angular2 Tutorial I'm doing. I have a gulpfile set up to compile all my typescript files, and serve it up to me in the browser. I created a simple component, and attempted to bootstrap the application using the Angular2 Bootstrap function. When I look in the terminal I can see that all the gulp tasks are running smoothly with no errors or issues, but in the browser the html element that is meant to be replaced with my Angular2 component is not doing anything ? I made some changes to my tsconfig file to get rid of some errors I was previously getting so maybe it was a configuration I changed that is not allowing the typescript to be compiled, but I am not really sure since there aren't any errors in the terminal.

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "types" : [
      "core-js"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "files": []
}
```

gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp')
var webserver = require('gulp-webserver')
var typescript = require('gulp-typescript')
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps')
var tscConfig = require('./tsconfig.json')

var appSrc = "./builds/development/"
var tsSrc = "./process/typescript/"

gulp.task('copylibs', function(){
    return gulp
        .src([
            'node_modules/es6-shim/es6-sham.min.js',
            'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
            'node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js',
            'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
            'node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js',
            'node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js',
        ])
        .pipe(gulp.dest(appSrc + 'js/lib/angular2'));
});

gulp.task('typescript', function(){
    return gulp
        .src(tsSrc + '**/*.ts')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(typescript(tscConfig.compilerOptions))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(appSrc + 'js/'))
});

gulp.task('watch', function(){
    gulp.watch(tsSrc + '**/*.ts', ['typescript']);
    gulp.watch(appSrc + 'html/*.html', ['html']);
});

gulp.task('webserver', function(){
    gulp.src(appSrc)
        .pipe(webserver({
            livereload: true,
            open: true,
            port: 9000
        }));
});

gulp.task('default', ['copylibs', 'typescript', 'watch', 'webserver'])
```

boot.ts

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core'
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser'

@Component({
    selector: 'myapp', 
    template: '<h1>Welcome to our app</h1>'
})

class AppComponent {

}

bootstrap(AppComponent)
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Learn AngularJS2: The Basics</title>

    <!-- Scripts to allow Angular2 and Typescript to work on older browsers -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/angular2/es6-sham.min.js" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/angular2/system-polyfills.js" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/angular2/angular2-polyfills.js" />

    <!-- Script for loading Typescript modules -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/angular2/system.src.js" />

    <!-- Something to do with 'observables' -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/angular2/Rx.js" />

    <!-- Angular Script -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/angular2/angular2.dev.js" />

    <!-- defaultExtension is 'js' so whenever we import a module, we don't have to include the js at the end. -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        System.config({
            packages: {
                js: {
                    format: 'register',
                    defaultExtension: 'js'
                }
            }
        });
        System.import('js/boot.js')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <myapp>Loading...</myapp>
</body>
</html>
```

Directory Tree

```
├── app.js
├── app.ts
├── builds
│   └── development
│       ├── index.html
│       └── js
│           ├── boot.js
│           ├── boot.js.map
│           └── lib
│               └── angular2
│                   ├── Rx.js
│                   ├── angular2-polyfills.js
│                   ├── angular2.dev.js
│                   ├── es6-sham.min.js
│                   ├── system-polyfills.js
│                   └── system.src.js
├── gulpfile.js
├── node_modules
├── process
│   └── typescript
│       └── boot.ts
├── tsconfig.json
├── typings
│   ├── globals
│   │   ├── es6-collections
│   │   │   ├── index.d.ts
│   │   │   └── typings.json
│   │   └── es6-promise
│   │       ├── index.d.ts
│   │       └── typings.json
│   └── index.d.ts
└── typings.json
```

Comment: Nothing in the browser console?

Comment: I also noticed you have no app module, which version of angular are you using?

Comment: No, unfortunately there are no messages in the console :/. I am using Angular version 2.0.0-beta.2

Comment: I suggest you use the most recent version. 2.0.0 final was released about 2 weeks ago and 2.0.1 was released as well. Many breaking changes were introduced since beta 2.

Comment: Did you look for errors in the browser console?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately nothing shows up. I checked the network tab in the chrome developer tools and noticed there wasn't any type of javascript file being used, but I wasn't sure if this was normal or not with Angular2, and the way they use Typescript.